# Update Row Value based in condition of another Column. Google Big Query

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Hi So im new using Google Big Query and SQL in general, im triying to find a code that do the exact same thing that this Spreadhseet formula
[sheet code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk16q.png))

The logic is if the value of the colunm Condition is the same that the row below (this case B3 = B4), then use the value in the row below of column new_string, if not use the value of the column string in the actual row

I tried using the command LEAD() and LAG() but never seem to find the result I want, not even close.

| Date | People | Condition | String | New_String |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/22/2023 18:08:16 | Mark | a | link1 | link1 |
| 2/20/2023 15:28:06 | Leny | b | link 2 | link 2 |
| 2/20/2023 15:08:12 | Rob | b | link3 | link 2 |
| 2/21/2023 20:08:44 | Mark | c | link4 | link4 |
| 2/18/2023 12:03:11 | Maggy | d | link5 | link5 |
| 2/16/2023 18:08:22 | Leny | e | link6 | link6 |
| 2/16/2023 17:33:43 | Mark | e | link7 | link6 |
| 2/16/2023 17:24:56 | Rob | e | link8 | link6 |

So in this case the table should be ordered first by date and then by the column people, in the rows that Condition is repeated I need to repeat the value of the column string. I want to create the column **New_String** that looks exactly like this

Answer (score -1):

You were on the right path with LEAD() and LAG(). You can basically use

```
IF(
  condition = LEAD(condition, 1) OVER (ORDER BY order_attribute), #condition in this row = condition in the following row
  LEAD(string, 1) OVER (ORDER BY order_attribute), #if yes, grab string from the following row
  string #if no, use the current string
) as new_string`
```

As you can see from the example, it is important that you come up with the "**order_attribute**".

Data in your sheet is already ordered, so if that's the data you are using you can simply add a column that corresponds to a row number (order_attribute in my code sample above).

Comment: I tried but still no success I posted more information about the order attribute that im using if you find this useful to understand better the problem

Comment: You have a case (condition e), where string is link6, link7 and link8, should all 3 end up with the same string?

Comment: Yes link6, link7 and link8 should end up in the same string for the column New_String